# Call a function from a button inside a label

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework, datepicker

I've started developing a small app using Ionic 1.

Here I've used `ionic-datepicker` external plugin as the date picker for my app.

I need to put the button inside of a label in the same row of an input field

```
 <label class="item item-input">
       <input type="text" ng-model="newEvent.date" placeholder="{{date}}">
       <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="openDatePicker()">
           Date
      </button>   
  </label>
```

I need to place the elements like this. But here, the function doesn't call. But when I place the same button outside the label tag it works.

Why is that? How can I make it happen?

Comment: I removed my comment because I wasn't sure if it's correct, but you can click on a label and associates it with an input via the `for` attribute, so putting a button there doesn't seem correct

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have multiple form controls inside a label. Start by fixing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label element intercepts the click event and focus the related input. I suggest to you wrap label and button inside a div element.